# Regular expression to capture both integer and float in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Can anyone help to capture the both int and float vaules using reg expression

I have below reg exp which will capture only int values but need to modify this for foot value also

```
'^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]*([kmg])b?[[:space:]]*$'
```

This works if the value is
eg `23 MB` but failing for
`23.789 MB`.

```
'^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:].]+)[[:space:]]*([kmg])b?[[:space:]]*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^[[:space:]]*([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?)[[:space:]]*([kmgKMG][bB]?)[[:space:]]*$
```

*Details*:

- `^` -  start of string
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then an optional Group 2 matching a `.` and then one or more digits
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([kmgKMG][bB]?)` - Group 3: `k`, `m`, `g`, `K`, `M` or `G` and then an optional  `b` or `B`
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$`  - end of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TbRE33/2).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the string containing your number is stored in variable `vstring`, the following should do:

```
if [[ $vstring =~  ([+-]?[[:digit:]]+([.][[:digit:]]+)?) ]]
then
  number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo No number in $vstring 1>&2
fi
```

This also assumes that a floating point has not exponential part (since you didn't mention it in your question). It works with i.e.

```
vstring="23.789 MB"
vstring=-35
vstring=18.167
vstring="The number is 0.987"
```